# Doing lag queries using hive on irregular timeseries

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to get a lag of one my column on an irregular time series. The data would be as follow

```
time stamp (seconds), temperature
1, 20
4,12
6,13
7,18
```

the new dataset should be as follow

```
time stamp (seconds), temperature, lagged_1_temperature
1, 20,0
4,12,0
6,13,0
7,18,13
```

As seen just the lag for last row is a non zero.

For a typical lag I use bellow hive query inside my spark application.

`"select timestamp, value ,lag(`value`,1) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as lagged_1_value"`

Can I change above hive query to give me the result I want

Comment: so..only when previous timestamp is current timestamp-1, you should show the lagged value..else 0..is that correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: Why do you consider it "irregular"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `case` expression.

```
select t.*,
case when timestmp-coalesce(lag(timestmp,1) over(order by timestmp),0)=1 
then coalesce(lag(temperature,1) over(order by timestmp),0)
else 0 end as lagged_1_termperature
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `left join` might be more efficient:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(tprev.value, 0) as prev_value
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.timestmp = t.timestmp - 1;
```